# problem changing CRS of a shapefile

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

[image]I am trying to change the CRS of one shapefile that is originally in NAD27 to WGS84. 
When I proceed to make the change, I still continue to see the file in UTM coordinates... 
I've tried to save the file as a new one with the and change it at the "set layer CRS" option...
Do you know another alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You should include the program you are using... But if your using QGIS I would avoid using the "Save as" option and instead open QGIS "Toolbox" find the QGIS Algorithm for Vector - "Reproject Layer" made sure to set the source CRS to nad27 and the target to wgs84

Comment: I tried it, and it keeps up showing UTM coordinates even though the metadata says the projection changed... :( I added a printscreen

Comment: Open the .prj file from the original shapefile package using any text editor, copy and paste the text here